# Regex matching numerical variable names

Tags: regex, plsql, regexp-replace

suppose that we have following string:

```
$6 
$7 

You have received the grade of $3 in the subject $1 ($10) in the semester $2 ($11). 
Grade date: $4 
Entered: $5
```

I need to figure out how to dynamically and corrcetly replace those variables. And suppose we have folloving `PL/SQL` pseudo-code:

```
for i in 1..X loop
  l_str := regexp_replace(l_str, '\$'||to_char(i), l_replace(i));
end loop;
```

But when it comes to first iteration - `$1`, `$10`, `$11` variables are being replaced - but only `$1` is correct.

Does anyone have advice how to fix it?

Comment: Try `l_str := regexp_replace(l_str, '\$[0-9]+\b','SOME_STRING');`

Comment: It is not a static replacement, I've changed example, sorry for mystification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regexp matches anything starting with $ and a current iteration number.
If you need to replace all those variables with the same string, you don't need a cycle there as you can simply do it like that:

```
l_str := regexp_replace(l_str, '\$[0-9]+','SOME_STRING');
```

if you need to have different different replacements, you can do it similarly:

```
for i in 1..X loop
  l_str := regexp_replace(l_str, '(\$'||to_char(i)||')([^0-9]+|$)',l_replace(i)||'\2');
end loop;
```

Comment: Actually, it should work according to: [link](https://www.regex101.com/r/bA2wL7/1), but the output remains unchanged. What I have found that "Oracle11g does not support Lookahead of Regex yet." - maybe that is the problem?

Comment: oh, sorry then. But do you need to replace vars with different strings, not the same one?

Comment: Yes, for example, $1 is name of the student, $5 should be replaced with date

Comment: Try this. I updated the answer. The idea is to find a var AND the rest which is non-digit, then in replacement to put your string AND the rest